# can we use post method in mail function to redirect to another page

Tags: php

While writing php mail function ..
    i need to put a link in that mail. and also i need to transfer two values to that target page
    . now i am using .

```
<a href='http://www.example.com/allow.php?id=$url&cat=$cat'>Click here to accept his request</a>
```

When user click this link that page will get those value.
But i have to use post method instead of get method . to prevent from knowing of ID and CAT.

Is there any chance to use post method in mail.
OR how to delete this link from url after load.
or how to encrypt this link..

Comment: no you can't use post in an email but you could always use a unique token that refers to a url, id & catagory. after the link has been clicked you could also choose to expire the token

Comment: using POST will not prevent that the user can see the values.

Comment: @LiamSorsby you should post this as an answer, it's the only viable option.

Comment: Apart from encoding the values in the url .. which is only security by obscurity and can be circumvented as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are unable to POST in an email, the only method to do this is to use a unique token. This can be, if required, expired once clicked which is used with things such as validating your email address. The unique token can the be linked via a database to link the token to the url and the id which you do not wish the user to see.

Comment: Also, instead of using an auto-incrementing ID, use a random string of some length (30 characters would normally do it).  That way people will find it hard to brute force into the URL.  If you want to make it really secure you can require the internal id to be sent along with the auth key (as you might name a generated string) and only accept the request if the auth key and id match.  (of course 'really' and 'secure' are used relatively).

Comment: @RobBaillie good point. I didn't actually think anybody would try and use an autoincrement on a unique token but nice little addition

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use POST method with a link, but the email sent may contain a whole HTML form, and with that you can use the POST method.
The disadvantage is that not every mail client will display correctly such an email.

Comment: The disadvantage ist that the values are just as easy to see in a POST form as in a link.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider: I thought the goal of this question is just to make it fancy.
For security concerns, you are absolutely right.

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot send a post request from a link in an email.
However, you can achieve your goal of not disclosing the variables to the client in a number of ways.

One way would be to have a databse table such as:

```
request_id | user_id | category
1            73        books
```

Where by you add a record when a user generates a request, and send the request_id in the email to the receiving user. Then you would look up the request_id and grab the user_id and category.

As mentioned by another user, you could also record when the request had been accepted/declined, set an expiry etc.

Another simpler way would be to use some 2 way encryption on the values, so the email contains the encrypted versions. Perhaps less secure, and less extendable, but probably quicker to set up.